# Namespace issues when calling a plugin variable

Tags: plugin-development

Making a plugin.

I can't seem to get this `{% set leads = craft.lead_infopack.getPacks() %}` to fire from within a template.

Plugin name: lead

Here's a look inside my variables class.

Lead_InfopackVariable.php:

```
class Lead_InfopackVariable
{ 
    public function getPacks()
    {
        return craft()->lead_infopack->leads();
    }
```

The leads function calls a service that outputs all entries within my 'infopack' table.

If I write it like this it works `{% set leads = craft.lead.getPacks() %}`

LeadVariable.php:

```
class LeadVariable
{ 
    public function getPacks()
    {
        return craft()->lead_infopack->leads();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some more info. What is that leads function?

Comment: Sorry updated my question with more info.

Comment: I could be totally wrong, but you might try `{% set leads = craft.lead.infopack.getPacks() %}`

Comment: No luck - with `{% set leads = craft.lead.infopack.getPacks() %}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can only have one variable class. So the solution you posted is the only way that works.

Answer (score 4):

[carlcs](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/9695/57) is correct (as usual).

You can only have one variable class that maps to `craft.pluginName`, but you can have methods inside that class that map to other variable classes.